# How to copy a reusable multi row/column table from one excel worksheet to a database on another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, user-input

I'm reasonably new to VBA coding and I was wondering if it is possible to do the following?

I have a reusable input worksheet that contains, amongst other elements, a table that has 24 columns and 10 rows. I'd like to be able to add however many rows have been completed into a database on another worksheet.
I've managed to find some code that allows for single row updating but no success for multiple rows.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Iain

The code looks like this:

Sub UpdateLogWorksheet()

```
Dim historyWks As Worksheet
Dim inputWks As Worksheet

Dim nextRow As Long
Dim oCol As Long

Dim myCopy As Range
Dim myTest As Range

Dim lRsp As Long

Set inputWks = Worksheets("Input")
Set historyWks = Worksheets("PartsData")
oCol = 3 'order info is pasted on data sheet, starting in this column

'check for duplicate order ID in database
If inputWks.Range("CheckID") = True Then
  lRsp = MsgBox("Order ID already in database. Update record?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Duplicate ID")
  If lRsp = vbYes Then
    UpdateLogRecord
  Else
    MsgBox "Please change Order ID to a unique number."
  End If

Else

  'cells to copy from Input sheet - some contain formulas
  Set myCopy = inputWks.Range("OrderEntry")

  With historyWks
      nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
  End With

  With inputWks
      'mandatory fields are tested in hidden column
      Set myTest = myCopy.Offset(0, 2)

      If Application.Count(myTest) > 0 Then
          MsgBox "Please fill in all the cells!"
          Exit Sub
      End If
  End With

  With historyWks
      'enter date and time stamp in record
      With .Cells(nextRow, "A")
          .Value = Now
          .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
      End With
      'enter user name in column B
      .Cells(nextRow, "B").Value = Application.UserName
      'copy the order data and paste onto data sheet
      myCopy.Copy
      .Cells(nextRow, oCol).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
  End With

  'clear input cells that contain constants
  ClearDataEntry
```

End If

End Sub

And the input table is attached[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwFuX.png)

Comment: Yes this is possible, please could you share your code and maybe a screenshot of how your data is laid out, to enable us to give an appropriate answer? Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to copy the entire new range in Workbook 1 and copy it, then past it into cells(lastrow+1,1) in the Database workbook.

Comment: Thanks Cyril - do you have an example code that I could look at? As I say, I've quite new to this so I'm not 100% certain of which commends etc. to use in which circumstances

Comment: @Iain just an FYI for the future, you should use @ username to call attention to the intended person, though you can only have one call per comment line, otherwise the person most likely won't know you've responded to them.  i happened to check on this as the name looked familar and only happened to see your comment to me.

Comment: @Cyril, thanks for that! Only just starting posting on here so still learning the ropes... and thanks for the code, I'll see if I can get that to do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example code in response to comment:

```
Dim lr as long, lc as long, lr2 as long
with ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source")
    lr = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
    lc = .cells(1,.columns.count).end(xltoleft).column
    .range(.cells(2,1),.cells(lr,lc)).copy 
end with
with Workbooks("Database").Sheets("Dest")
    lr2 = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
    .cells(lr2+1,1).pastespecial xlvalues
end with
```

Comment: with a slight modification that worked perfectly, thank you

Comment: @Iain So this doesn't remain open, would you please accept the answer, and specify what modification you made?

Comment: mods were to sheet names and cell row/column refs so that it copied to a specific region on my target sheet.

Comment: @Iain ahh, so standard stuffs.  wasn't sure if you meant you had to change how the with statements worked or any objects.  Thanks!

Comment: standard it may be but quite new to me! But I’m getting there I reckon...